# TMemo descendant with empty lines

Tags: delphi, vcl

My TMemo descendant has constructor

```
constructor TMyMemo.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Lines.Clear;
end;
```

When I put TMyMemo on the form I get error "Control '' has no parent window.". Why?

Comment: Why are you publishing Lines in the first place if you ignore its settings. Derive from TCustomMemo instead.

Comment: @David - I wish to put "empty" memo on the form. Often / always then I put TMemo on the form I clear lines. I am very lazy :)

Comment: You've got an excellent answer now but this question is also a fine illustration of why you should explain your underlying problem.

Comment: I love the idea of having captionless controls (tpanel, tmemo, etc).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A newly created memo has no content. But content is added as soon as the component acquires a name, which is done automatically by the designer. To prevent this, remove `csSetCaption` from `ControlStyle`:

```
constructor TMyMemo.Create(AOwner: TComponent); 
begin 
  inherited Create(AOwner); 
  ControlStyle := ControlStyle - [csSetCaption];
end;
```

Comment: Great answer. I think I'm going to create a MyPanel and MyEdit too. :) Or is it an option you can toggle in the designer?

Answer (score 0):

Move Lines.Clear to overriden method CreateWnd. Underlying window control (multiline edit) doesn't exist during Create execution

Comment: This clears the content whenever `CreateWnd` is called, which happens more than you would think.