# How to set caption in TPanel descendant during construction?

Tags: delphi, vcl

```
TMyPanel = class(TPanel)
public
  procedure AfterConstruction; override;
end;

procedure TMyPanel.AfterConstruction;
begin
  inherited AfterConstruction;
  Caption := '';
end;
```

I want to clear the caption during construction, but this code does not work as I expect.
It will not set the caption to empty string.
If I assign ' ' (space) to Caption, it will remain, but this is not a proper solution.

I am using Delphi 2006.

Comment: If the Caption is not empty during designtime, then assigning empty string during construction doesnt have any effect.

Comment: If you want a panel that, by default, has no Caption when you drop it on the form, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850176/tmemo-descendant-with-empty-lines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
uses
  ExtCtrls, StrUtils;

type
  TMyPanel = class(TPanel)
  public
    procedure Loaded; override;
  end;

procedure TMyPanel.Loaded;
  inherited;
  Caption := EmptyStr;
end;
```

Tested and appears to work fine in XE2.

*EDIT*:

The reason this works where the method shown in the OP doesn't is because `Loaded` is called *after* the object's property values have been assigned from the DFM file.

The overridden call to `AfterConstruction` takes place after the initial creation of the object, but *before* the property values have been assigned from the Form's DFM, meaning that whatever property values you assign in your `AfterConstruction` method will be immediately replaced by whatever value is specified for that same property in the DFM.

`Loaded` takes place *at the very end* of the construction order, so whatever value you assign there will be final.

Comment: Thanks, it works! By the way why are you assigning EmptyStr instead of ''? The documentation says it is provided for backwards compatibility only.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained why it solves the problem. I mean, I know why it does, but for the benefit of those that don't know an explanation would be useful.

Comment: I use EmptyStr because I hate defining String Literals in  code (even if it's only an empty string). I would rather have common strings defined the once, and reference that constant/resource thereafter.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan answer expanded to explain *why* it works. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Loaded has the drawback of not being called when components are instantiated at runtime as this means the streaming system is not used. I'd use the constructor and change/override the value (only) if after the inherited call (which also does the streaming when a component is streamed in) it is still the same as before that call.

Comment: @MarjanVenema This won't work because the `constructor` is called *before* the DFM property values are set, so any values you set in the constructor will be replaced (at design- and run-time) by the DFM-defined values. In the case of TPanel, this includes the annoying Caption default value.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Still, fact remains that Loaded is only called when a component is streamed from a dfm. So you can't rely on Loaded either.